# Rxjs Operators: Breaking Changes

Tags: angular, rxjs

It appear something has changed in Rxjs version and having real problems trying to rework some old code.

From what i have read on other posts here it appears i need to use pipe but when i try revised code i then get a type issue.

Using "rxjs": "6.5.2",
        "rxjs-compat": "6.5.2",

Any suggestions or help would be appreciated.

**Current Code**

```js
import { Observable, combineLatest, of } from 'rxjs';
import { switchMap } from 'rxjs/operators';

currentUserRoles: Array<string>;
currentUserRolesData: Array<Role> = [];
allRoles: Array<Role>;
combineRoles$: Observable<Role[]>;
```

It is saying Property 'switchMap' does not exist on type 'Observable<[{}[], {}[]]>'.

```js
async setCurrentUser(user: User): Promise<any> {
    this.currentUserRoles = user.roles;

    const rolesWithCustomerId = this.afs.collection('roles', ref =>
        ref.where('customerId', '==', user.customerId)
    );
    const rolesWithUserId = this.afs.collection('roles', ref =>
        ref.where('customerId', '==', user.id)
    );
    this.combineRoles$ = combineLatest(
        rolesWithCustomerId.valueChanges(),
        rolesWithUserId.valueChanges()
    ).switchMap((cities: [Role[], Role[]]) => {
        // tslint:disable-next-line:no-shadowed-variable
        const [rolesWithCustomerId, rolesWithUserId] = cities;
        const combined = rolesWithCustomerId.concat(rolesWithUserId);
        return Observable.of(combined);
    });
}
```

**Revised Code**
Error Type 'Observable' is not assignable to type 'Observable'

```js
async setCurrentUser(user: User): Promise<any> {
  this.currentUserRoles = user.roles;

  const rolesWithCustomerId = this.afs.collection('roles', ref =>
    ref.where('customerId', '==', user.customerId)
  );
  const rolesWithUserId = this.afs.collection('roles', ref =>
    ref.where('customerId', '==', user.id)
  );
  this.combineRoles$ = combineLatest(
    rolesWithCustomerId.valueChanges(),
    rolesWithUserId.valueChanges()
  )
  .pipe(switchMap((cities: [Role[], Role[]]) => {
    // tslint:disable-next-line:no-shadowed-variable
    const [rolesWithCustomerId, rolesWithUserId] = cities;
    const combined = rolesWithCustomerId.concat(rolesWithUserId);
    return Observable.of(combined);
  }));
}
```

Comment: Can you post the entire error?

Comment: In the revised code, are all of the rxjs operators being imported from rxjs and not rxjs-compat? Looking at the error it feels like you might be trying to cast an Observable from the new version to an Observable from the compat version, or the other way around.

Comment: Try changing `Observable.of(...)` to `of(...)`.

Comment: https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/docs_app/content/guide/v6/migration.md. In brief, you need use pipe and change the imports to 'rxjs' and 'rxjs/operators'

Comment: You might need to use combineLatest with brackets inside: combineLatest([...]). I am not sure since what version it is needed to do so.